# MAMP MySQL seems to be running extremely slow

Tags: mysql, performance, wamp, mamp

Ever since I imported a fairly large database MySQL seems to be running horribly slow, there are times when my local sites just sit there loading and loading and loading and an error never displays. In the status bar in chrome it just says "Sending request..." All of my HTML only sites load instantly, however anything that has to access the database just will not load. This issue seems to happen randomly. I can be working on my local sites just fine for about 30 mins, then all the sudden MySQL decides to turtle on me. I'm thinking its a memory issue but I honestly have no clue what's causing it. Anyone have any ideas to try?

Answer (score 2):

First, try installing some tools to monitor your general memory and CPU usage:

- OS X includes a utility called *Activity Monitor* that is a more visual version of the unix `top` command and includes some simple history graphs.  If you look at Activity Monitor when your computer is running slow you can click on a column heading to sort by it (sorting by descending "CPU %" or "Real mem" may identify an active culprit).
- There are several more subtle monitoring tools such as [Menu Meters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/), which includes a helpful set of Menubar Extras.  The menubar extras are updated in real time, so you can configure info of interest and that may also give you some hints when resources are low.

If you have periodic slowdowns, this could also be when your computer is either allocating/removing swap files for virtual memory .. or swapping active memory to disk.  Either of the above utilities should give you some hints on swap allocated/used and whether that allocation is changing quickly.

Then, take a look at some MySQL-specific usage:

- enable the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html) in MySQL; it will help you find queries that are not optimal
- when the slowdown happens, try using the `mysql` shell to see what queries are currently running via:

  ```
   show processlist
  ```
- there is also a console utility [`mytop` utility](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) you can install which is handy for monitoring the MySQL processlist (it automatically refreshes, like the unix `top`).  I believe you can also use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) to do similar admin monitoring from a shinier GUI, but I haven't used this recently.

Hopefully the above give you some ideas to help track down the general issue.  Once you can find out why the slowdown is happening (low resource, missing indexes, bad queries, ..) then you can take appropriate steps to correct.

The [O'Reilly High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do) book is also a very informative read :).

Comment: MAMP also comes with a copy of Sequel Pro, which has an auto-updating process list available in the Database menu.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems that could happen:

1. you have locks (in a console run "show innodb status \G" at the time the app is slow to verify this).
2. you might get out of memory and your machine could be swapping (if unix verify with top or sar).
3. you could have indexing/queries that take a long time to execute, to verify this you can check the slow query log:
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

These are only a few of the things that can affect performance but probably some of the most common. If this didn't help you need to add more details to your question.

Comment: How do I run "show innodb status \G"? Not really sure what top or sar is either, sorry  :(

Comment: Just open a console and run the command. See more information here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/17/show-innodb-status-walk-through/

Comment: You haven't detailed the OS where your DB resides. In UNIX you would access the top command that describes processes and mem usage, I guess in windows you can use the task manager.

Comment: mac runs a unix flavour hence you have top. Just open a terminal on the machine you have the database and run "top"